# How can I download Syzygy tablebases efficiently?

Tags: tablebases, download-games

How can I download Syzygy tablebases (5-man or 6-man) as quickly as possible without clicking hundreds of links at a mirror? Is there a verified torrent available that will probably download faster and use less resources than a mirror?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found out wget supports mirror site listings, so I used

```
wget --mirror --no-parent --no-directories -e robots=off http://tablebase.sesse.net/syzygy/3-4-5/
```

It might take a few tries to download all files since occasionally 403 Forbidden is returned (maybe should wait between requests). Then run `md5sum --check checksum.md5` to ensure everything is all downloaded. Still I think a torrent is a more robust way to download huge files.

Answer (score 3):

This link is for 3+4+5: https://thepiratebay.org/description.php?id=10530043.
As for 6 or 7, I'll try to find them later.

Comment: I usually use TPB for "other purposes" but I'll take a look

Answer (score 2):

The Internet Archive has torrents for the Syzygy (and other) tablebases

https://archive.org/search.php?query=subject%3A%22tablebases%22

The file view gets a little confusing due to being classified as audio, but you will find the torrent files among them.
[Syzygy 6-man WDL torrent](https://archive.org/download/Syzygy6WDL/Syzygy%206men%20WDL.torrent)
[Syzygy 6-man DTZ torrent](https://archive.org/download/Syzygy6DTZ/Syzygy%206men%20DTZ.torrent)